# Need to combine array elements to match id's needed to print into table cells

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

What I have is a table coded in HTML that has 10 rows and 10 columns, and each cell has it's own ID:

```
<table id="ch4">
<caption>
     Multiplication Table
</caption>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">*</th>
        <th scope="col">1</th>
        <th scope="col">2</th>
        <th scope="col">3</th>
        <th scope="col">4</th>
        <th scope="col">5</th>
        <th scope="col">6</th>
        <th scope="col">7</th>
        <th scope="col">8</th>
        <th scope="col">9</th>
        <th scope="col">10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td id="oneX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td id="twoX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td id="threeX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td id="fourX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td id="fiveX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">6</th>
        <td id="sixX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">7</th>
        <td id="sevenX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">8</th>
        <td id="eightX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">9</th>
        <td id="nineX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">10</th>
        <td id="tenX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I also have very basic multiplication nested for loops:

```
    for(var i=1; i <=10 ; i++){

    for(var j=1; j<=10; j++){

        document.writeln(i * j);

    }

}
```

I know it's not correct for my application, but you got to start somewhere.

Essentially what I need to do is put the output from this loop, into the corresponding table cells, to get an outcome that looks something like this:

```
    x  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    2  2  4  6  8  10 12 14 16 18 20
    3  3  6  9  12 15 18 21 24 27 30
    4  4  8  12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
    5  5  10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
    6  6  12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60
    7  7  14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70
    8  8  16 34 32 40 48 56 64 72 80
    9  9  18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
    10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

One of the issues I'm having is that to obtain all of the table cell id's in the script, I have to combine two arrays to match the id's.

```
    var rowID = ['zeroX', 'oneX', 'twoX', 'threeX', 'fourX', 'fiveX', 'sixX', 'sevenX', 'eightX', 'nineX', 'tenX'];
    var colID = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
    var combID = " ";
```

And I'm confused as how to do so. I'm new Javascript and haven't really ever touched it until now. Should I loop the arrays? I don't know.

Comment: Can you include HTML and the JavaScript that you have tried at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you should get familiar with JavaScript, write down the algorithm try to isolate the problem you are trying to solve, then the solution will show up. You can query the DOM for elements ids, types... and then when you want use the .InnerHtml or .Text property to assign or change the values of the cells. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a given HTML table, you coudl just iterate the given arrays for getting the id and assign a value to `innerHTML`.

```
var rowID = ['zeroX', 'oneX', 'twoX', 'threeX', 'fourX', 'fiveX', 'sixX', 'sevenX', 'eightX', 'nineX', 'tenX'],
    colID = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr, td,
    i, j;

for (i = 1; i <= rowID.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < colID.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById(rowID[i] + colID[j]).innerHTML = i * j;
    }
}
```

You could create a table with the wanted parts by iterating the given arrays.

```js
var rowID = ['zeroX', 'oneX', 'twoX', 'threeX', 'fourX', 'fiveX', 'sixX', 'sevenX', 'eightX', 'nineX', 'tenX'],
    colID = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr, td,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i <= rowID.length; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j = 0; j < colID.length; j++) {
        td = document.createElement(i && j ? 'td' : 'th');
        td.id = rowID[i] + colID[j];
        if (i === 0 && j === 0) {
            value = 'x';
        } else if (i && j) {
            value = i * j
        } else {
            value = i + j;
        }
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
td { text-align: right; }
```

Comment: The only issue is that the table has to be in HTML, and the two arrays have to be combined to match the cell id's.

Comment: Added. Sorry bout that.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work by replacing rowID.length and colID.length with 10. It's works to what I need. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the arrays you have created:

```
for(var i=0; i <10 ; i++){

    for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
        //for printing out first row/column:
        var product = i==0 ? ( j==0 ? 'x' : j ) : ( j==0 ? i : 0 );
        if(product==0)
               product = i*j;
        document.getElementById( rowID[ i+1 ] + colID[j+1] ).innerHTML = product;

    }

}
```

In place of colID array, you could use the array index plus one.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is already generated in the format you show, you don't need the id's in order to set them. Just grab all cells's of your table with `querySelectorAll()` or similar method, and iterate over that collection setting using the index of the cell in that collection as a way to calculate the number for that cell.

```js
var table = document.querySelector('#ch4');

//colSize is number of child td elements in the row (minus the th elements)
var colSize = table.querySelector('tr').children.length-1;
var list = table.querySelectorAll('td');

list.forEach((element,index)=>{
  index+=1;
  var row = Math.ceil(index / colSize);
  var col = index % colSize;
  element.innerText = (col?col:colSize) * row;
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table id="ch4">
<caption>
     Multiplication Table
</caption>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">*</th>
        <th scope="col">1</th>
        <th scope="col">2</th>
        <th scope="col">3</th>
        <th scope="col">4</th>
        <th scope="col">5</th>
        <th scope="col">6</th>
        <th scope="col">7</th>
        <th scope="col">8</th>
        <th scope="col">9</th>
        <th scope="col">10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td id="oneX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="oneX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td id="twoX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="twoX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td id="threeX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="threeX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td id="fourX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fourX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td id="fiveX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="fiveX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">6</th>
        <td id="sixX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sixX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">7</th>
        <td id="sevenX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="sevenX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">8</th>
        <td id="eightX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="eightX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">9</th>
        <td id="nineX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="nineX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">10</th>
        <td id="tenX1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX9">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tenX10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```